# Importing several CSV files and create separate tables SQL server tables based on each file

Tags: sql-server, powershell, bulkinsert

I have no SQL experience and have have 70 + CSV files I need to import into an SQL server database. What I need to do is automate this or simplify this so I can run a script and import them all and have them create a new table for each csv file.  Some of the files are huge so ideally need a large column width (1000 ) for each.... Some have hundreds of columns...  Any assistance would be great... I have seen some scripts but none seem to do the job I need

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to use `openrowset`. Plenty of examples exist demonstrating how.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `openrowset` you can take advantage of the ability to to `select into` a destination table that's created automatically.

It's a process that's not free of various hurdles you may need to overcome however I've had to do this many times and have had the best luck with the following syntax:

```
select * /* into <destinationtable> */
from OpenRowset(
 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
 'Text;IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=0;Database=<path to folder containing file>',
 'select * from filename.csv'
)x
```

The OLEDB driver works best when you have a *schema.ini* file located in the same folder as the source file.

See [how to create a schema.ini file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) for details.

Also obtain the [latest oledb 16](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) drivers here.